# Pointer alignment issue

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, alignment

I have the content of a file already loaded in memory and I want to assign the data from the file to a convenient set of structs, and I don´t want to allocate new memory.

So I have the pointer of the memory where the data from the file starts, from there I work down this pointer assigning the values to different structs but then I reach a point where the program crashes.

```
//_pack_dynamic is the pointer to the data in memory
us *l_all_indexes = (us *) _pack_dynamic; //us is an unsigned short

printf("Index 0:%d", l_all_indexes[0]); //here is where the program crashes

_pack_dynamic += sizeof(us) * m_number_of_indexes;
```

The data, at least for the first element, is there, I can get it out like so:

```
us temp;
memcpy(&temp, _pack_dynamic, sizeof(us));
```

Any idea how I could extract all the indexes (**m_number_of_indexes**) from **_pack_dynamic** and assign them to **l_all_indexes** without allocating new memory?

Comment: The structs are packed and the data is aligned correctly, yeah?

Comment: What's `us` ? Why it can be printed? Also I see some missing parentheses.

Comment: Yes. I packed the file in python using little-endian (it is for a little endian processor). Before, I had it working with new memory allocations but decided to get rid of that.

Comment: @ Eugene Sh "us" in an unsigned short, sorry I missed a parentheses on the printf while copyng the data (the code compiles)

Comment: In C++ it's undefined behaviour, use `std::memcpy` instead.  It might also be UB in C you will need to check the standard.

Comment: @ Richard Critten How would extract the array from _pack_dynamic (it has m_number_of_indexes elements) and paste it on l_all_indexes) without allocating new more memory?

Comment: Its not possible

Comment: what type of pointer is `_pack_dynamic`? Looks like this violates [strict aliasing rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule)

Comment: @yano the type is void *

Comment: you can use a `union` to associate the pointers together, something like `union{ void* _pack_dynamic; us* _pack_dynamic_us; };`, then use the `us*` when you need it,, I think that will correct your UB. If you're still crashing after that obviously there's other problems.

Comment: @ yano Didn´t know you could do that, thanks for the tip! I have a bunch of different types (not only us) so I guess it would have to go back to memory allocation and memcpy

Comment: Sure,, take a look at the strict aliasing link in my previous comment and do some googling for "type punning"

Comment: "extract all" --> `us extract[m_number_of_indexes]; memcpy(extract, _pack_dynamic, sizeof *extract * m_number_of_indexes);`

Answer (score 0):

Accessing `_pack_dynamic` as if it contained `us` object(s) has undefined behaviour unless it actually does contain such objects (this is a slight simplification, but a good rule of thumb. An array of `char` certainly cannot be interpreted as `short`).

The `memcpy` way into a proper `us` object is the only standard way to interpret memory as an object. Another approach for integers is to read char by char and shift-mask-or them together. This approach allows assuming a particular endianness instead of native.

A system dependent way that might work is to make sure that `_pack_dynamic` is aligned to the boundary required by `us`. But even then, standard gives you no guarantees about behaviour.

"Allocating" an automatic variable has hardly any runtime overhead. Allocating a few bytes for a `short` is usually insignificant.

Comment: ok, thanks for the explanation, I guess I will have to go back to previous version and allocate new memory and use memcpy instead.